# Polimorfismo Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

No contexto da herança, quando `B` é sub-classe de `A`, uma instância de `B` poderá ser usada em qualquer sítio onde uma instância de `A` é válida. Esta é a característica do polimorfismo. No entanto tenho uma dúvida.
Sei que é correto:

```
A oa = new A();
B ob = new B();
A oab = new B();
```

No entanto, isto também é correto?

```
B oba = new A();
```

E se for, gostaria de saber porque.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pense que `B` é `Poodle` e `A` é `Cachorro`. Todo `Poodle` é um `Cachorro`, mas o contrário nem sempre é válido.

Por exemplo:

```
// Ok. Em uma variável do tipo Poodle, dá para colocar um Poodle sem problemas.
Poodle w = new Poodle();

// Ok. Poodle é um Cachorro, então dá para colocar em uma variável do tipo Cachorro.
Cachorro x = new Poodle();

// Ok. Cria algum vira-latas genérico e coloca em uma variável do tipo Cachorro.
Cachorro y = new Cachorro();

// Não! Não dá para se afirmar que um cachorro genérico é um poodle.
Poodle z = new Cachorro();
```

Comment: Obrigada! Já compreendi :)

Answer (score 5):

Não é correto porque `B` é mais específico que `A`. Isso compilaria se você fizesse um *cast*:

```
B oab = (B) new A ();
```

Isso porque, embora aqui seja o operador `new`, um objeto que viesse de uma variável do tipo `A` poderia ter sido criada a partir de uma subclasse `C` que não fosse compatível com `B`:

```
class C extends A{...}

A myA = new C ();
B myB = myA; // aqui precisa falhar a computação
```

Mas se você coloca o *cast* basicamente está dizendo para o compilador confiar em você.